# Handling raised exceptions redddit api prawler

Tags: python, reddit

I am trying to make a script to automatically post on subreddits

```
    for sr in subreddits:

    id = reddit.subreddit(sr.strip()).submit_image(title='Prettiest in all the land... comments?', image_path=path)
    print(sr.strip())
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(sr.strip()).new(limit = 1):
        try:
            print(submission)
            id = submission.submit_image(title='Prettiest in all the land comment', image_path=path)
        except :
           print('Exception working')
```

praw.exceptions.RedditAPIException: SUBREDDIT_NOTALLOWED: 'This community only allows trusted members to post here' on field 'sr'

my question: Why doesn't try handle this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're showing I believe you're asking why doesn't the try block catch that specific error.

You can do a few things:

1. If you don't know the specific errors you might get (more than a few different ones for different things) you could put a generic `Exception` catch in your block.
2. You can specifically add your exceptions in your `except`.

With exceptions you generally want to be as specific as possible, so generic `Exception` blocks aren't recommended because then you're targeting less specific scenarios.

```py
try:
    # something
except Exception as e:
    # generic exception
```